# Compiling Simulink Code into .ELF object form

Tags: matlab, compilation, elf, simulink

I have a simple model from simulink and I would like to generate code using the code generator in the simulink and then compile it using gcc into a .ELF object file. How can I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the product called Simulink Coder (around matlab 2011b) or Real-time Workshop (for older matlab versions). Typing ver at the matlab command window will show what products and licences you have installed.

If Simulink Coder or RTW are installed, you use the menu Simulation->Configuration Parameters to set up the model for code generation.

If you have Embedded Coder you can set System Target File to ert.tlc, and this will produce a very concise main() routine to call your model code. Otherwise, use grt.tlc which produces a lot more bloat then ert, but is the only useful one available for on Windows.

There are a lot of options to go through and check - it really needs someone with a bit of experience to be present!

As you are requesting an ELF file, is this for an embedded system? If so, there is a lot more work to be done. If the target is not one of the already supported targets, then you need a target package, which will take either a lot of time and experience, or money to buy one.

Custom target development - a world of it's own:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/rtw/ug/bse3b2z.html